# OpenLayers 3.13v: issue with ol.format.GeoJSON()

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In OpenLayers 3.13v, I obtain `Uncaught AssertionError: Assertion failed: format must be set when url is set` with ol-debug.js, while `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'V' of undefined` with ol.js

I use the following code by replacing `ol.source.GeoJSON` [in this example](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch08-interacting-with-your-map/example-01.html)

```
  var vectorEuropa = new ol.layer.Vector({
    id: 'europa',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      projection: 'EPSG:3857',
      url: '../assets/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson'
    }),
    style: defaultEuropa
  });
```

Moreover, I have the same issue if I try to create an empty layer like [in this example](https://openlayersbook.github.io/ch07-wrapping-our-heads-around-projections/example-04.html)

```
  var bbox = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector({
         format: ol.format.GeoJSON()
     })
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass an instance to the source's `format` option:

```
var vectorEuropa = new ol.layer.Vector({
  id: 'europa',
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: '../assets/data/nutsv9_lea.geojson'
  }),
  style: defaultEuropa
});
```

Also note that there is no `projection` option for `ol.source.Vector`.

If you want to create an empty source, you should not be setting a `format`:

```
var bbox = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector()
});
```

To add features to the source above, you will need to create them with geometries in the view projection, and e.g. use `bbox.getSource().addFeatures`.